# Read textfile data from specific position to end

Tags: c#

i am trying to read textfile data from specific position to end.i have a staring positon like 5 & end position 18
and i am reading my textfile as below.
1234      12134

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\TXTFILE.txt");
var a = lines[0].Substring(5, 18);  // 1234      12134
```

But i am getting error as below :

> Index and length must refer to a location within the string.

from 5 to 18 data have space charactores at starting & end.

Please let me know how to fix this bcz i dont want to trim these white spaces.

Comment: your specific starting position and end position to read, is referred to file or to each line in a file?

Answer (score 0):

```
   public string Substring(
        int startIndex,
        int length
    )
```

Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring **starts** at a specified character position and has a specified **length**.

18 isn't your length, your probally looking for 18-5 = 13.
The exception is occuring since your string isn't as long as you think(18 + 5 = 23 chars).

In your case the string you inputted here is only 16 chars long so I have no idea about what you are trying to acheive here.

Example:

```
string str = 'testing this';
string newStr = str.SubString(0,2); //  'te'
string newStr2 = str.SubString(1,4); //  'esti'
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The line must contains atleast `23` characters when you try to get substring `start index 5` and `length next to 5th index is 18`.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\TXTFILE.txt");

foreach(string line in lines)
{
      if(line.Length >= 23)
      {
          var a = line.Substring(5, 18);
      }
}
```